# Best practice to use SCSS and its variables with MUI v5 components?

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, sass, material-ui

I'm starting a project with React and planned to use SCSS for styling and MUI for some of my components.

I understand that some MUI components do not accept SCSS overriding some of its properties and that it is better to use `styled` in this situation. However, it sometimes turns out that you can achieve the same result simply by adding `!important` to your scss classes.

So let's suppose that I want to style a `AppBar` and override its `background-color` with SCSS. Which of the two following is the best practice, and why?

### The first one, with `styled`, that I use now

My `header.tsx`

```
import { styled } from '@mui/system';
import variables from '../../../styles/_variables.scss'
import './header.scss';

const MyAppBar = styled(AppBar)({
  backgroundColor: variables.blue,
});

<MyAppBar className="Header" id="topbar">
         ...
</MyAppBar>
```

My `header.scss`:

```
@import '../../../styles/styles.scss';

.Header {
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 50px;
}
```

My `_variables.css` :

```
/* COLORS */
$blue: #155092;

:export {
    blue: $blue;
}
```

This solution works but requires a `styled` component and some export from the scss file, which makes the whole thing a bit heavy

### The second one, with `!important` :

Basically, remode the `styled` component, use a simple `AppBar` with `Header` as a `className` on `header.tsx`:

```
import './header.scss';

<AppBar className="Header" id="topbar">
         ...
</AppBar>
```

And use the following `./header.scss`:

My `header.scss`:

```
@import '../../../styles/styles.scss';

.Header {
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: $blue !important;
}
```

This one is lighter and probably easier to read.

However, I'm not a huge fan of using `!important` on my classes as I see it as unclean and a bit unscalable.

Which solution is better? Or should I look for an alternative?
Thanks for your advices !

Comment: I am running into a similar problem right now. How did you decide in the end?

Comment: @ErikBrendel I used the first option with the injectFirst option to have my scss code take priority.